# Cannot mix Aggregate and Non Aggregate Arguments Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, visualization

I have the following data:

```
Date1         Records                    
26-03-2020     22
21-03-2020     10
25-07-2020     5
21-03-2010     12
31-01-2020     13
01-01-2020     11
05-09-2010     04
```

So I am trying to create a calculated parameter such that

```
if year(Date1) = 2020 and month(Date1) in ('Jan', 'Feb' ,'Mar', 'Apr', 'May') then count(records)
end
```

Expected output

```
Date1         Records                    
Mar-2020      32    #22+10
Jan-2020      24    #13+11
Jul-2020      5
```

> Error: Cannot mix Aggregate and Non Aggregate Arguments

Comment: not clear what you're trying to do, but give this a try: drag Date1 to the Rows shelf and change it to month. drag Records to the Text card. the result is something like what you describe, with no formulas needed. and by the way, you have two dates that are 2010 instead of 2020.

Comment: Hey i know this, so i need this for some other reasons , to colour and label the points with specific dates only. Can you please tell the formula way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
count(if year(Date1) = 2020 and month(Date1) in ('Jan', 'Feb' ,'Mar', 'Apr', 'May') then [records] end)
```

IN only works in the latest version of tableau I think. Therefore, an alternative formula could be:

```
SUM(INT(YEAR([Date])=2020 AND MONTH([Date])<6))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just one request, I want the count of record id not the sum (for the 2nd formula). Can you please help

Comment: A count of record id is the same as a sum of 1 which is what the second formula is doing. However, if you want a countd of record id then change the COUNT to COUNTD in the first formula (and change the month part of it to match that in the 2nd formula, it's more efficient)..